# I have my probation ending at the end of this month, is it better to bring up salary increase before or during it?

Tags: management, salary

So I joined my current company 5 months ago (approx) they asked me to join while I was working at my old company, at the time they told me that after 6 months they would increase my salary up 2k, but recent atmosphere indicates they are trying to save money, I spoke to the director of the company and he said he would bring it up with the other directors at the end of february, I'm worried he either forgot, or is ignoring it.
I recently had my responsibilities increased dramatically and my contract changed from a mere 1 week notice to 2 month notice. (I understood the reasoning and accepted it) The person's job who I took over was on double my current wage

So I suppose the question I'm asking is, how do I bring this up with my boss if he doesn't bring it up with me when he returns on monday?

Comment: I don't think your circumstances are special enough to diverge from your regular "How to ask for a raise" situation. See [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid).

Comment: @Denslat - was the additional 2k offer in writing anywhere (contract,  email)?  If not they may "forget" they ever discussed it.

Comment: Does probation = criminal probation or the usual 3 to 6 month "probationary period" that many companies use?

Comment: Is the probation period two sided, or one sided (option for the company)? If the latter, you're probably out of luck. If the former, you need to engage before the probation ends, as you would then have no leverage over them not keeping the deal.

Comment: @sevensevens In this context, it means a 3-6 period in employment where the employee can be let go without any reason or documentation required, and often without severance pay unless it was negotiated into your contract.

Comment: Bring it up after you're onboard. If you rub them the wrong way, they could potentially let you go on the spot. Next week, follow up on the pay increase. If it wasn't guaranteed in writing and they decline to follow through with their verbal promise, either live with it, or start looking for new work if it's that significant an issue to you. Best of luck!

Comment: @OweJessen In reality, probationary periods are only theoretically two-sided (often by law). You actually have more leverage, not less after it has ended.

Answer (score 5):

If they made you a promise, even if it was verbal and not written (you should have asked for it in writing though), then there is nothing at all wrong with asking them to make good on it. If he doesn't bring it up himself then simply bring it up at the end of the day/meeting/whenever you see him. You will not be punished for inquiring about a promise that was made to you. This is business, you can't be afraid to negotiate. If you do it in a respectful way the worst you'll get is a no.

Answer (score 1):

A probation period is meant for both the employer and the employee to make sure you are both getting what you want out of the deal. As such, I would definitely initiate negotiations before the end of the probation period, so that you can respectfully bow out if things don't end up where you want them to.

As far as I know, situations like the one you describe are typically used by companies to try to get you to keep working for the current salary and forget about the promised increase in pay. You should evaluate for yourself whether or not you would be happy to continue working for the company under what you currently think your responsibilities and what your compensation will be.

If you're happy with the current situation and the better situation would be 'nice to have', be cautious in your negotiations and just take what you can get. If you won't be happy unless you get what you want out of the negotiations, make sure it's clear to the company that they stand to lose you if they can't conclude the negotiations to your satisfaction.